# integrating C# and Java

Tags: java, c#

We have the following scenario:

- There is a program (already written) in Java which runs on a server (in the web). Let's call it `JavaServerProgram`. It takes user input, calculates stuff and finally generates a bunch classes. Let's call these classes `JavaClasses`. All these classes are serializable to json.
- There is a library (already written) in C# that contains many classes describing a tree-like data structure. Let's call it `C#Data`. Let's call the root class `C#Root`. All classes in `C#Data`are (de-)serializable to/from json.
- The bunch of `JavaClasses` that `JavaServerProgram` outputs can be converted into a `C#Root` instance. We have a library written in C# for that which takes json representations of the `JavaClasses` as input and creates a `C#Root` instance. Let's call it `C#Convert`. This library will always be needed by another project; i.e. it can not be discontinued.
- There is a program (already written) in C# that takes an instance of `C#Root` and does some actions (like shown a GUI, modifying files, ...) on a client. Let's call it `C#ClientRun`.

The workflow should be like this:

1. `JavaServerProgram` runs *on the server* and outputs `JavaClasses`.
2. The `JavaClasses` are converted into a `C#Root` instance *on the server*.
3. `C#ClientRun` gets the `C#Root` instance as input and runs *on the client*.

**The question is, how do we implement the whole thing?**

---

Version A:

We use all already existing programs and libraries. That means:

- We modify `JavaServerProgram` so that after creation of the `JavaClasses`, it serializes them into jsons and outputs them.
- We write a C# program that takes the json representations of the `JavaClasses` from `JavaServerProgram` as input, uses `C#Convert` to create a `C#Root` instance, serializes the `C#Root` instance to json and outputs it.

Then, after `JavaServerProgram` has run, we run that C# program and finally send the resulting `C#Root` json to the client where it will be derserialized into a `C#Root` instance and input into `C#Run`.

Pro: We use existing code.

Con: We have overhead due to

- the conversion being an own program (it takes time and memory for the OS to manage it),
- "media discontinuity": Instead of directly converting the `JavaClasses` into `C#Root`, we must serialize them to json (in Java) to be able to send them to the converter. (The converter does NOT deserialize them to `JavaClasses`, though. It processes the jsons directly.)

---

Version B:

We make a Java clone of `C#Covernt`, i.e.

- we duplicate all classes from `C#Data` in Java as well as their ability to be serialized to json,
- we duplicate the conversion algorithm in Java but without using jsons in-between, i.e. we directly convert from `JavaClasses` to `C#Root`.

Then we extend `JavaServerProgram` to contain the above clone, i.e. after creation of the `JavaClasses` it converts them into a `C#Root` instance and serializes it to one json. Then we send that `C#Root` json to the client where it will be derserialized into a `C#Root` instance and input into `C#Run`.

Pro: We have no own-program-overhead and no "media discontinuity".

Con: We need to maintain the `C#Data` classes and the conversion algorithm in two languages (C# and Java).

---

Version C:

We find a way to write code both in C# and Java but compile it to some common intermediate language that runs in one shared environment (like JVM / .NET-VM).

Pro: No duplicate code and no overhead/"media discontinuity".

Con: Cannot see any. (The time needed to get to know this new environment does not count as a con since it will be just invested once.)

---

**Can anyone elaborate pros and cons from a practical perspective?** Like:

- Version A: Will the expected overhead be relevant? Or is it going to be small?
- Version B: Is maintaining duplicate code in different languages practical? Is it common? Are there tools to assist? (Maybe there are tools that can automatically convert from C# to Java?)
- Version C: Does such an environment as described exist? Which one? Has anyone experience with it?

Comment: A few questions for understanding: It basically comes down to a webservice being called by the client application, right? You seem to have 2 distinct models which need to be transformed in one or both directions, correct? Does that conversion _have_ to happen on the server? If so, why? And why doesn't the Java server application provide that model right away? Is that other model used elsewhere too?

Comment: To address some of your questions: "Will the expected overhead be relevant? Or is it going to be small?" - That depends and is hard to answer without knowing much more. I'd say think about longer term maintenance and what's really needed. Chose the implementation that is the most efficient while meeting non-functional requirements (the overhead might not be relevant enough to warrant a complex implementation).

Comment: "Is maintaining duplicate code in different languages practical? Is it common?" - I'd say it is common enough. Whether it's practical again depends on the circumstances. There are for sure tools that translate between languages but those have their limitations but as long as you stick to basic language features you should be fine.

Comment: you can look into mono if you want to compile Java to .NET https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/java/ I'm not saying you should just use it, but you can do your own research on it before making your choice

Comment: @Thomas question answers 1: Yes, basically a webservice being called by a client application. Yes, we have two distinct models (`JavaClasses` and `C#Data`) and we need to transform the first into the second.

Comment: @Thomas questions answers 2: Why conversion on the server? Because the amout of data in `JavaClasses` is much greater than in one `C#Root` instance. So if the conversion happened on the client, the webservice had to send much more data. It's basically a performance/throughput question. But honestly, I don't know what outweights the other: Either we send larger amount of data and then convert efficently on the client, or we convert not-so-efficienlty on the server but then send just a small amout of data to the client.

Comment: @Thomas question answers 3: The target model (`C#Data`) was created based on what should be achieved in `C#Run`; both were developed simultaneously. They are not finished; new functionality will be added and this might need some adjustments in `C#Data` (and the conversion, respectively). The input model `(JavaClasses`) was created based on what should be achieved in `JavaServerProgram`; those two were also developed simultaneously. Adjustments in `JavaClasses` are less likely but still possible.

Comment: A candidate for version C could be [WebAssembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAssembly).

Answer (score 2):

I would probably prefer the Version B alternative.

From my understanding that will create a clean separation of concerns between java and c#, i.e. all Java runs on the server, all c# on the client. They will also share a common object model of the objects that need to be transferred. Note that the data format should be clearly documented, so it is obvious what side is incorrect if there are any issues.

You might also consider making a entirely separate API between the client and server, even if it may happen to look very similar to some existing data structures. That could let you evolve the API without necessarily needing to affect other systems.

But your question implies that this library is used in other contexts, so I would probably recommend figuring out what language to use in what situations. Otherwise you will keep running into problems like "Code from project K would be perfect for project L, but is in the wrong language". As well as risking various employment issues. I.e. holy language wars, conflicts, knowledge gaps, extra training, recruitment difficulties etc.

Version A will do extra work on the server that might or might not cause a performance overhead, but more importantly it will make debugging more difficult, since it might be difficult to tell if the error is in the java code or the conversion code. And the server developer may not be able to debug the c# code efficiently.

Version C is a nice thought, but even if it is possible it would be a uncommon solution. So you will likely have much more issues with build systems, compatibility and finding help when there are issues.